# Foreach item hover different background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a hovering animation, here's my code

```css
.blocks {
    position: relative;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
}

.blocks .item-1 {
    background-color: red;
}
.blocks .item-2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
.blocks .item-3 {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.blocks .item-4 {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="item-1">Hello</li>
        <li class="item-2">Hi</li>
        <li class="item-3">How are</li>
        <li class="item-4">You today</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="blocks">
    <div class="block item-1"></div>
    <div class="block item-2"></div>
    <div class="block item-3"></div>
    <div class="block item-4"></div>
</div>
```

I want for example, when you're hovering with your mouse `<li class="item-2">Hi</li>`, the `<div class="block"></div>` with the same class displays and the others hide.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: You have to use jquery or javascript for your purpose.

Answer (score 3):

A simple bit of jQuery script to register a hover event, hide all the other blocks and show the currently hovered classes element is all thats required.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu li').hover(function() {
    $('.blocks .block').hide();
    $('.blocks .' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
.blocks {
  position: relative;
}
.block {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.blocks .item-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.blocks .item-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.blocks .item-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.blocks .item-4 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="item-1">Hello</li>
    <li class="item-2">Hi</li>
    <li class="item-3">How are</li>
    <li class="item-4">You today</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block item-1"></div>
  <div class="block item-2"></div>
  <div class="block item-3"></div>
  <div class="block item-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you could add an `stop()` before the animation. Don't know if its just me, but that endless transitions makes me dizzy :P

Comment: `hover` is triggered multiple times if the mouse is moving on top of the element.. I think is better to use `mouseenter` for this

Comment: The poster may want to have the text in `<span></span>` and trigger the animation on it to make sure it only changes when hovering over text.

Comment: The hover event does only run when hovering over the text due to the fact that jQuery is looking for `.menu li`

Comment: Can't the `li` be the length of the page, regardless of the text size? - in the snippit above, the animation runs when hovering on the right side of the page

Comment: @Cory that's down to the OP. My code works from the OP's supplied code. and it wouldn't be a difficult change to implement.

Comment: @ Stewartside . true, was just making a suggestion to OP - not a comment on the code you provided

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jQuery example:

```
$('.menu li').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.blocks .block').hide();
    $('.blocks .block.' + $(this).attr('class')).show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('.blocks .block').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utkfLfwq/)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this jQuery code:

```
$(".menu li").mouseenter(function(){
    $('.blocks .block').hide();
    $(".blocks").find("."+$(this).attr('class')).show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $('.blocks .block').hide();
});
```

Hope it helps..